# How to deliver a BLE message to an iOS app that isn’t running?

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on a device that sends a message/signal to an iOS app via BLE. It currently works fine if the app is running in the foreground or background; however, I need the device to deliver this signal to the app when it isn’t running so it can process it, in essence, “waking it up.”
A device that seems to be doing this well is Tile (used to keep track of keys, etc.). The Tile can signal the phone even when the Tile app isn’t running, making the Tile app come up and sound an alarm. My use case isn’t the same, but I need to achieve the same behavior.
Does anyone have any pointers as to how to achieve this? The OS needs to launch/wake the app upon receiving this BLE message/signal from my device.

Comment: Please look up "state preservation and restoration" for Core Bluetooth.

Comment: "state preservation and restoration" will not work because the app is not relaunched after the user force-quit the app. I'm looking for something that still works after force-quit and even device reboot.

Comment: No, the engineers at Apple aren't smart enough to make that work :(

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?